# scp file as another group

Tags: scp, group

I would like to `scp` a file, however my *primary* group does not match the permissions of the destination directory so I get a permission denied message when I try to `scp`. I have the correct group as a *secondary* group, and I can change to that group using `newgrp`, but it reverts when I open a new connection.

Is there a way of changing my group inside an `scp` call?

Comment: The solution proposed using `sg` will work, but I want to point out that it *should* work even without that if you have the group as a secondary group and the permissions allow write access by that group. Also by the way, you tagged your question "cgroups" which is wrong (cgroups is something else) so I will edit it.

Comment: I'm guessing what happened is that originally, in runnning scp the secondary group wasn't there, and then the group was added later.  The fact that groups aren't automatically updated in existing sessions, might explain this. Dunno though.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the scp in a [sg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sg.1.html) command. For example:

```
sg yourgroup scp ....
```